# How to stop Windows 11 from putting drop shadow on desktop icon label?

Tags: windows-11, user-interface

After installing Windows 11 22h2 and setting up all my applications and using it for a week or so, windows decided it had to do an update. After the update i noticed all the desktop animations had come back ( which i had turned off ) and desktop icon label drop shadows had reappeared ( which i had also turned off ). Going back into the system->properties dialog and unchecking the 'Show drop shadows on desktop icon labels' makes no difference. The drop shadows make it much more difficult to read the text on the desktop and so I really prefer they not be there.

Comment: You might consider uninstalling the `KB5031354` update. This will fix the shadow issue, but at the same time you should be aware that this update is a security update that protects against `CVE-2023-44487`.

Comment: @kanlukasz - thanks for the advice i will leave this latest microsoft bug in place.  reminds me of dilbert's $10 bonus for every bug fixed ... https://i.imgur.com/tyXXh1d.png

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove drop shadows on Desktop icons as of right now (10/11/2023).

Desktop icons were screwed up by Microsoft in the next to last Windows updates.

At this point, and despite clear feedback (which at this point has not been acknowledged), there is no correction in sight. You cannot fix this issue in any reasonable way because it is internally broken in Windows.

Perhaps the 23H2 (not yet reality) will fix this issue.

> **Follow up:**  With the most recent Windows Updates,  (1) removing (disabling Dropped Shadow)  and also (2) disabling Smooth Edges of
> Screen fonts does help, BUT,  some text items are bad and the cure
> here is worse than the disease.
>
> So NOT properly fixed at this point.

**Further Follow up October 26 2023:**  Windows 11 Update today 10/26/2023 to 22H2 22621.2506 along with a .NET Framework Update and the option to remove Drop Shadow is WORKING.  Fixed finally.

Comment: In my experience ( task scheduler going over summer time clock change ) when microsoft breaks something, they never fix it.

Comment: Task Scheduler has nothing whatever to do with drop shadow. It is a Windows issue not yet fixed.

Comment: Task Scheduler is part of the same piece of software as desktop drop shadows, namely microsoft windows. I've been waiting for microsoft to fix it since windows server 2003 and it's still broken in windows server 2019.

Comment: I understand that, but your question is  "can dropped shadow be fixed"  ,   Answer - No not at this time.  Later maybe but right now, no.

Comment: This has been fixed and I amended my answer. @Barny

Comment: My PC did an update last night ( 18th Nov 2023 ) and now desktop font shadow problem has been fixed - great news ! However the update has created a new problem. Windows now goes to sleep even though sleep is disabled. This makes my PC unusable when i try to access it remotely. It would appear the days of windows being problem free are well and truely over. Windows XP just worked. Windows 11 on the other hand is permanently broken !

Comment: It is still broken in Win11 23H2, for me.

Comment: Windows 11 since 22H2 has properly fixed dropped shadows and the fix has held.  Still correct in 23H2

Comment: For you, perhaps, John.  Not for me.

Answer (score 1):

The icon text shadows were forced on for me by "2023-10 Cumulative update for Windows 11 Version 22H2 x64 -based systems ([KB5031354](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-10-2023-kb5031354-os-build-22621-2428-ecc07685-218f-4ba9-b3c8-fe2e35059aec))" released on the October update Tuesday (2023-10-10).

Putting automatic updates on hold and removing that update fixed the problem for me (for now).

An alternate solution I found was disabling font edge smoothing in the performance options (in addition to the icon text shadow), but I can't stomach the ugly text that results in.

---

That being said, Microsoft have failed to fix issues with icon text shadows since at least 2015, so I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for a solution.

Here's a [locked thread from 2015-2017 on Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/desktop-icon-labels-have-drop-shadows/024c601c-3247-4c36-803e-9626ea38ae98?page=2). The required workarounds (either disable window snapping, or use solid color desktop background) remain the same to this day (before this latest update).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of 10/12/2023 the drop shadow can still be removed.  Go to the usual System Properties and select the Settings button as described in many other links and posts. Then make sure that both the "Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop" and "Smooth edges of screen fonts" options are de-selected.  The drop shadow on the desktop icons should now be off.  At least it worked for me.

Comment: Am running windows 11 pro 22H2 with latest updates, and if i turn off edge smoothing then while the shadow is certainly less noticeable, the shadow is still there. Disabling font smoothing effects everything though, not just the desktop icons.

Comment: It will not work if `KB5031354` is installed, unfortunately.

Comment: Drop shadows were corrected in October and all is working fine now.

Comment: Another cumulative Windows 11 update out today - try updating and setting Drop Shadow again.

Comment: Not for me. Win 2019.